# CSS Pie Chart with different PHP values

Tags: php, css, pie-chart

I am trying to create a CSS Pie Chart script that will display three sets of results every time, every time these results appear, they will be different. i.e I am using different pie charts across the site that will display different information.

I want to know how I would do this, I have managed to write the PHP that will give my 3 sections rotate starts and total values of each segment, but actually implementing the rest of the pie chat is quite hard.

PHP for determining size of each area and it's total rotation:

```
<?php 

    $T1 = $degree['UFIRST'];
    $T2 = $degree['UUPPER'];
    $T3 = $degree['ULOWER'];

    $TotalTs = $T1 + $T2 + $T3; 
    $PieTotal = 360 / $TotalTs;

    // AREA OF SLICES %'s

    $Slice1 = $T1 * $PieTotal;
    $Slice2 = $T2 * $PieTotal;
    $Slice3 = $T3 * $PieTotal;

    // ROTATION %'s

    $StartSlice1 = 0;
    $StartSlice2 = $Slice1 + $StartSlice1;
    $StartSlice3 = $StartSlice2 + $Slice2;

    ?>
```

This is my HTML for each segment:

```
<div class="pie" data-start="0" data-value="<?php echo $Slice1 ?>"></div>
<div class="pie" data-start="<?php echo $StartSlice2 ?>" data-value="<?php echo $Slice2 ?>"></div>
<div class="pie" data-start="<?php echo $StartSlice3 ?>" data-value="<?php echo $Slice3 ?>"></div>
```

All of this is correct and works, however I don't know where to start with writting the CSS for this, as I don't wish for it to be a static pie chart.

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated.

Please no links or mention to jQuery examples as I wish to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend using Google Charts API, as it is relatively simple to implement but it requires Java Script.

Another option is to use plain CSS charts based on circles and their sectors which an example of can be found [here](http://atomicnoggin.ca/test/pie-chart.html)

Comment: All the degree's options here are static, how do I make them change based on the start and end value?

Comment: You won't be able to deliver dynamic values to css without JS. The only option with the pure css graphs would be to have the predefined html & css graphs and call them with PHP. As @user2486415 mentioned, JS is a key here for dynamic results

Answer (score -1):

Well on of the best charts are jquery if you want to write it yourself you should post at least what you have so far.If you want them be dynamic you want to use js, even for static you still need to use js.Bcs entering manually css value through php is just meh.